# Android ScrollView with list view but disabled scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I am developing an android app with base API11. I wanted to add a list view in a scroll view with all other components but i know that is not right. So, i made list view static like expands when new cells are added but when i add the scroll view, the list view becomes scrollable. Please find the xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groupNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Group Name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/grpName"
            android:layout_below="@id/groupNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter group name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grpDescriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Group Description"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/grpName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/grpDescription"
            android:layout_below="@id/grpDescriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter description"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/individualEA"
            android:layout_below="@id/grpDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Individual's Email addresses"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/individualEA"-->
            <!--android:orientation="horizontal">-->

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/addEmailAddressButton"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/individualEA"
                android:src="@mipmap/add_button"
                android:background="@color/whitecolor" />
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/addEmailAddressButton"
        android:id="@+id/eaListView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/twoButtonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/eaListView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/updateButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/create_account_button_bg"
                android:text="Update"
                android:layout_below="@id/eaListView"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/delete_account_button_bg"
                android:text="Delete"
                android:layout_below="@id/eaListView"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:padding="7dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The screenshot below is what i require but screen is not scrollable and list view static and expanding. This happens when i comment the scroll view and relative layout.
[image]

In order to make it scrollable, i add the scroll view and relative layout but the scroll view makes list view scrollable and reduces the size of the list view like shown in screen shot below.
[image]

In landscape mode, it works the other way by making the screen scrollable and list view static.

My question is how do i make the screen scrollable with list view static and expanding like in the first screenshot both in portrait and landscape?

P.s: i thought of using recycler view and card view but the base API is old hence i was unable to proceed with the same.

Thank you

Comment: Why you not try ExpandableHeightListView

Comment: Have you tried NestedScrollView? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Expandableheightlistview

Gradle

compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'

xml code

```
  <com.github.paolorotolo.expandableheightlistview.ExpandableHeightListView
                android:id="@+id/driverlist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@drawable/separator_gray1">
</com.github.paolorotolo.expandableheightlistview.ExpandableHeightListView>
```

other source code is remaining same as Listview
write this line after set adapter

```
listview.setExpanded(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix a ScrollView with a ListView or anything that can scroll.

Just use Listview HeaderView or/and Footerview.